# alarm stop's when signal arrive

Tags: c, unix, signals, alarm

I'm trying to combine signal and alarm.
I have 2 Processes. 1 is receiving input from the user, and write it into pipe and then sending signal (SIGUSR2) to the other Process.
In the other Process, i have infinite loop which Produces alarm every second.
So my program should handle both alarm signal's and SIGUSR2 signals.
The alarm handle work fine, but when a signal arrive and the signal handler active it seem to don't return to the loop that Produce alarm's.
I read the man page of alarm and signal's and didn't find anything. It says that the signal handler function should return to the original code, but it doesn't.
I like to know why the code don't return to the loop after the signal handler, and how to force it to do the alarm handler function every second even if signal's received meanwhile.

this is the loop:

```
while (1) {
signal (SIGUSR2 , signal_hand);
signal (SIGALRM , alarm_hand);
alarm (1);
pause();
}
```

This is the signal handler function:

```
void signal_hand (int sig) {
// reading from the pipe and doing things accordingly
...
}
```

And this is the alarm handler function:

```
void alarm_hand (int sig) {
// doing things
...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eevery time you get a `SIGUSR2` (or any kind of signal at all), you repeat the `while` loop, and that resets your alarm timer to 1 second. That means that if the `SIGUSR2` signals come more than once per second, your alarm never goes off.

Try making the following changes:

- Move the two `signal()` to configure your alarm handlers outside the loop. There is no need to reset your signal handlers every time through the loop. Once they're set, they're set.
- Don't call `alarm(1)` in the loop after a `SIGALRM` might not have been received.
  Instead, call `alarm(1)` once before you start the loop and again to reset the timer from inside the `alarm_hand` function.

Comment: First, it don't return to the loop, because also if
 just 1 SIGUSR2 signal arrive it don't active the alarm. i waited 10 seconds and it did nothing.
I did moved the signal handler outside the loop, thank you.
But if i move the alarm(1) outside the loop and calling it again inside the alarm handler function it did the alarm function only once. Beside, the loop does nothing but alarm(1) and pause(), so if i move them outside the loop, i can earse the loop entirely.

Comment: It should certainly return to the loop. `pause()` returns after a signal arrives. Why don't you add some debugging `printf()`s to the loop to convince yourself of which lines of code are executing when?

Comment: Well, it worked, i just needed to declear the alarm handler function also inside the alarm handler function. Thank you very much!